# APT Installation Error

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

I'm getting error while trying to install something. I can't get so much thing from error because of my English language ( I'm Turkish ).

For example while installing nasm;

```cpp
>>> sudo apt install nasm                                                                                                                                                           
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nasm
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 382 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3.345 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 nasm amd64 2.15.04-1
  Could not connect to tr.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (193.140.98.183). - connect (113: No route to host)
E: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nasm/nasm_2.15.04-1_amd64.deb  Could not connect to tr.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (193.140.98.183). - connect (113: No route to host)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *groovy gorilla* [20.10] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.10 is 22 October (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/groovy-gorilla-release-schedule/15531) when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: This is not relative with Groovy Gorilla

Comment: I get this error also in focal fossa ( dual boot )

Comment: You won't get that error message on *focal* - refer https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nasm&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all as that message is specific to *groovy*, it's a *groovy* package.  If you're getting that message on a *focal* system, your *sources* are really badly messed up, and i'd suggest using `ubuntu-security-status` to assess the damage, as you'll discover your system isn't *focal* anymore, no longer a LTS with non-LTS components having been introduced.

Comment: Is there a way to install 20.04 packages to 20.10 or downgrade to 20.04 from 20.10

Comment: Ubuntu uses Debian's *deb* package tools (`dpkg`, `apt` etc) which will upgrade to the latest packages automatically, but have capacity to go backwards, as your backup strategy should already cater for that (be it via file-system and rollback, or traditional backup).  You can go backwards via re-install though, but some older packages (ie. programs) may not cope well with data files written by later programs, so accessing that potential-risk is all on you (unless your backup strategy already planned for that).

Comment: I just started getting errors today, I installed things like latte dock, powershell, zsh and more

Comment: Please read my first comment. This is not a *groovy* support site, so we can only help you here post-release (ie. 22-October).  It's currently a *development* release and whilst quite a lot of us use it (I've been using *groovy* since April), it has support areas as I mentioned in the first comment, but this is **not** one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The tr archive server for ubuntu is throwing the error

Change the http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu.

Do an

```
apt-get update
```

and then try to install

```
apt install nasm
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, tr archive server should work and it was working. Tr archive server is Turkey's server

Comment: The Turkish archive server you are using seems to be down. Use another server instead of `http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` ; for example, you can use `http://ubuntu.turhost.com/ubuntu/`